# Pop up caption on mobile view?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So, I created this caption inside my image, to show up when the user hover with the mouse over a symbol as you can see on the image

[image]

As expected (I guess), it doesn't work on mobile/tablet because of the size of the image.

How can I make it so when the user clicks on the image (on mobile and tablet size) for the caption to pop up (outside of the image, so the user can read it?

Like so: [image]

Thanks

HTML

```
<div class="col-5 col-sm-2 ml-auto aboutMid aboutMid1">
                            <figure class="cap-left">
                                <img src="assets/about/about1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                <figcaption>
                                    The house is a converted farm building featuring traditional wooden shutters and terracotta toof tiles
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
```

CSS

```
    figure { 
    display: block; 
    position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}

figcaption { 
    position: absolute; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75); 
    color: white; 
    padding: 10px 20px; 

    opacity: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
    left: -30%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition:    all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition:      all 0.6s ease;
}

figure:hover figcaption {
    opacity: 0.9;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
}

figure:before { 
    content: "?"; 
    position: absolute; 
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75); 
    color: black;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius:    12px;
    border-radius:         12px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 24px;
    /* Only Fx 4 supporting transitions on psuedo elements so far... */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    opacity: 0.75;  
}

figure:hover:before {
    opacity: 0;
}

.cap-left figcaption { bottom: 0; left: -30%; }
.cap-left:hover figcaption { left: 0; }
.cap-left:before {  bottom: 10px; left: 10px; }
```

My JS imported from bootstrap

```
     <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple bootstrap modal, which you would only trigger if you are on a mobile device or a certain window width.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh46ruvq/2/)

Add a bootstrap modal and make sure it does not get any unwanted custom css, you can add it outside of all your custom `div` to prevent that.

[Bootstrap modal, which I used](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#live-demo)

Then you use simple JS:

```
$("figure").click(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 960) {
    $('.modal-body').html($('figcaption').text());
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

It checks on click whether you are on a small device and (in my case under 960px width) and if true and opens the modal, otherwise nothing will happen.

In addition you could check for mobile devices like this:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}
```

The last part is from:

[What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

Comment: I copied, to try and did not work. Am I forgetting something? the top Scripts part I believe are from Bootstrap?

Comment: You checked the fiddle? Which version of bootrap do you use?

Comment: For modals you need `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.js`

Comment: I have the bootstrap implemented yes. What happen is "the caption now appears, but since it is too big, it doesn't show all, and the modal doesn't come out.. bootstrap-4

Comment: You need to make a fiddle yourself then, so I can check whats wrong. Probably you click on the figure? My example works with a click on figcaption, but it is easy to make it work with figure, depends what you need.

Comment: I need it to be on the image (for mobile only). Let me make a fiddle

Comment: I updated the fiddle and the answer. Also dont forget to add jQuery above bootstrap.js

Comment: I must be doing something wrong... gonna post on my question the JS and jquery I imported from Bootstrap to see if it is correct.

Comment: Its not a modal, but the caption appearing inside the image, like on desktop but of course you can't read.... I am super puzzled xD

Comment: You are missing the css: `<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: gonna try again

Comment: Here is the example with your css and js files: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh46ruvq/3/)

Comment: this is my page. Can you check why it isn't working? https://jsfiddle.net/TryFiddleRee/mbku9yt3/#&togetherjs=Ig9EPxq2Hp

Comment: tested on iPhone 6, iPad2 and One Pus 5

Comment: It works for me, make the preview of the fiddle smaller and reload, it considers the initial preview bigger then 767px.

Comment: try here on your phone: railsend.rc8.me and you will see what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Bootstrap 4 card utils with [image overlays](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#image-overlays) because they work everywhere.

Here's an example to get you started:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    .card-img-overlay {
        display: none;
    }
    .card:hover .card-img-overlay {
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 offset-3">
            <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
                <img class="card-img" src="https://placehold.it/400" alt="Card image">
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```